# proving that a matrix has one solution for any c1,c2

Tags: matrices

it is given that for this matrix there is one solution
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  a&b&0\\
  c&d&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

prove that for any c1 and c2, the matrix will have one solution
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  a&b&c1\\
  c&d&c2
\end{array}
\right] $$

Comment: can you share with us what you have tried?

Comment: I have no idea how to start

Comment: A start is to write down what is means that there is a solution - and if that doesn't help, write it down in a different way.

Comment: Also, may it be that the exercise assumes that there is *only* one solution or maybe *exactly* one solution?

Answer (score 0):

We know that the vector $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is a solution to the first matrix, so we know that if $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c&d\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}e\\f\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ then $e,f=0$.

Now, suppose there were two solutions to $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c&d\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}e_1\\f_1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\end{bmatrix}$$ $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c&d\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}e_2\\f_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Then, we know that $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c&d\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}e_1-e_2\\f_1-f_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ which is a contradiction. Hence, we know there is at most 1 solution.

Now, assume that there are no solutions to $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c&d\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}e\\f\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\end{bmatrix}$$That implies that $\exists k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $k\cdot\begin{bmatrix}a\\c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}b\\d\end{bmatrix}$ Why?, because if not, then we know that two independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ must span $\mathbb{R}^2$. Hence, we know that $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c&d\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}-k\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$Which again is a contradiction, so there must be at least one solution. Hence, we are done.